# How to create dynamic getting a value of form?

Tags: html, forms, dynamic, extract

I want to create website which working like this:

```
<form>
Do you wanna see more questions?
 <select name="first">
  <option>No</option>
  <option>Yes</option>
 <select>
</form>
```

If user selected option "No" nothing happens.
If user selected option "Yes" get a few new questions.
**Of course without click any button**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an ID to the select like `id = "first"`

Then you could grab the select dropdown using Vanilla JS, and get its text value like:

```
var dropdownElementFirst = document.getElementById("first");
var selectedItemsText = dropdownElementFirst.options[dropdownElementFirst.selectedIndex].text;
```

`selectedItemsText` will hold the value of "yes" or "no"

edited:

Watch the select option changing with a change event in js

```
first.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(first.value == "yes")
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't works 100% like I would like to. I check the value of po by document.write, when I change the value to "yes", the variable generated by the script does not refresh, but shows "no" all the time

Comment: I edited my answer. If you want to watch if the value changes, use a change event and handle the logic from there.

Comment: I'm delighted, everything works as it should. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably looking for something like a `radio button`. You can learn more about them here: [W3Schools Radio Buttons in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)
I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Without clicking any buttons". How would you get user input otherwise?

Comment: Yes, usually when there are two choices, like a yes/no you should use a single-select radio button group

Comment: My point is, if the user selects "yes", they don't need to click Submit, only the page will generate more questions that are hidden. I know the radio and that's not it.